# Retrieve routing wildcard (**) value

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Is there any way to retrieve (and display) the current wildcard (**) route to the user?

So one for example could display its value like this:

> Sorry, but the page "/WrongUrl" does not exist

## Edit

To be clear, this question is about displaying the url for UI purpose. Not how to create a correct route for a 404 error.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/Location#members

Comment: @JBNizet That seems to work. If you post it as an answer I could approve its as solving the question.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a [Location service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#members) that allows (among other things) getting the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Current route is available as `url` property in [`Router`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) and [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute).

It is a string in `Router`, `events` observable should be subscribed in order to track its changes:

```
router.events
.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
.subscribe(({ url }) => {
  this.currentUrl = url;
});
```

It is an observable of parsed url segments in `ActivatedRoute`, it should be serialized to string:

```
activatedRoute.url
.subscribe(urlSegments => {
  this.currentUrl = '/' + urlSegments.join('/');
});
```